# AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function whilre creating DB for FLASK project

Tags: python, flask

As I am trying to create the DB for this online tutorial I am getting the error below when I run the following command in python environment

```
from api import db,create_app
db.create_all(app=create_app())
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
  File "C:\JS_Class\tests\ng-blog\api\__init__.py", line 21, in create_app
app.register_blueprint(blogs)
  AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: blogs.wrapper
```

Can Someone push me into the right direction for this as I am stuck and I don't know where to look for more answers...

https://github.com/VladDumitru87/ng-blog

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems to be with the routes inside `api/Blog/blog_routes.py` that are decorated with `@jwt_required`. For example:

```
@blogs.route("/delete_blog/<int:id>", methods=["DELETE"])
@jwt_required
def delete_blog(id):
    blog = Blog.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    db.session.delete(blog)
    db.session.commit()

    return jsonify("Blog was deleted"), 200
```

From looking at the [documentation](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basic_usage/) and trying your code out it seems that it should be `@jwt_required()` instead of `@jwt_required`. So it should look more like this:

```
@blogs.route("/delete_blog/<int:id>", methods=["DELETE"])
@jwt_required()
def delete_blog(id):
    blog = Blog.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    db.session.delete(blog)
    db.session.commit()

    return jsonify("Blog was deleted"), 200
```

Change this for all instances where you use `@jwt_required` in that file.